# very fast (25Hz) div content update

Tags: jquery, html, server-side

I would like to update content of div block in displayed page with a refresh rate at least 25 times per second. 
The content that is a subject of change should be downloaded from remote server. Download size less than 1kB, generated html content approx 10kB.
I tried jQuery:

```
function test(){
$( "#message" ).load( "http://www.server-side/content.php" );}
```

but with

```
setInterval(function(){test()},50)
```

I achieved max refresh rate 5 times per second (5Hz)
is there any other technique to get faster response time of updating div content?
i am not sure if this problem is related to updating page or getting the source of update. Perhaps different method of accessing server side content is needed?

Comment: Try web sockets; you’re unlikely to get separate HTTP requests to happen that fast.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible, but a *very* tall order.

To start with, if you use an interval of 50 in setInterval, it will max out at 20 times per second, not 25.  More importantly, this will depend tremendously on a lot of factors, including some that may be outside your control.  Server speed and latency are likely the biggest bottlenecks.  Some browsers may have a hard time keeping up, as well.

I'd suggest that you use the Chrome developer tools (hit F12), particularly the network tab.  Look at how long it takes to make each request, how long the server takes to respond, and how long the transmission of data takes.  Even over a very fast connection, it takes some time to "fill the pipe" with TCP/IP, so you will not max out the theoretical connection speed.  Depending on the numbers you see, you may need to improve the server speed, refactor your code, or consider a different host.

A much better solution would be HTML 5 sockets or a plugin that can maintain a continuous connection.  The constant connect/transmit/disconnect of doing this by AJAX is likely to be too slow to achieve 25 Hz.